# Opposite of subpar... superpar?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

If something can be "on par", and "subpar", can something be described as "superpar"? Is there an accepted way to describe something as extraordinary with this term?

Comment: No. You're better off using another way to say "better than average." Besides, while *subpar* means inferior in most things, being *under par* in golf means doing better than average.

Comment: The usual distinctions are _"n" under par, par, birdie, eagle, double eagle, hole-in-one_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typical phrase is *above par*. *Superpar* is not a word in common use.

Comment: Note that "sub par" means below average and "above par" means above average, not "extraordinary" as you use in your question. If you say, e.g. "Mr Jones, your performance as an employee this past year has been above par", that's a mild compliment, not high praise.

Comment: Good point @Jay, I was answering more the title than the body.

Answer (score 2):

How about [nonpareil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonpareil)? Same Latin root as *par*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that the word you would use in this case is *superb,* meaning excellent or outstanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Interesting, and I like it. I doubt that it's etymologically related to "par", though. Curious if you find otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the use of surpar perhaps? Meaning above par of course, rather than super-par which could be confused as extraordinary.
Surpar (or serpar). E.g. surpass or surtitles (subtitles when they are above).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would never be spelled *serpar* because the prefix needs to be *sur-.* "Normalize" may be overstating things since even OED doesn't mention any historical use at all.